# VB.NET - Selecting Record In DataSet from Combo Box

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

Good evening all,

I am working on a windows forms application in vb.net using a remote MySQL database.  I have populated a combo box from the database with names.  What I am trying to do, is use the combo box as a navigator.  When the user selects a name from the combo box, it should navigate to the matching record.

I have successfully populated the combo box using the following code:

```
    Public Sub populateSelector(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim dbConn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.mydbConnStr)
        dbConn.Open()
        Dim sqlCboPop As String = "SELECT fldLastName, fldID FROM tblData WHERE fldLocation = '" & CurrentUserRecordSet & "'"
        Dim daCboPop As New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCboPop, dbConn)
        Dim dsCboPop As New DataSet
        daCboPop.Fill(dsCboPop, "tblData")
        With tsbCboSelect.ComboBox
            .DataSource = dsCboPop.Tables("tblData")
            .DisplayMember = "fldLastName"
            .ValueMember = "fldID"
        End With
    End Sub
```

This part ^^^ works fine.

However, I have been to the end of the interwebs and back trying to figure out how to select a record in the dataset based on the combobox.  I was able to successfully execute this in Access vba in a previous project, but have not been able to get it working in Vb.Net.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- M

Comment: You should be setting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` before the `DataSource`.

Comment: Why are you declaring arguments sender and e when you never use them in the sub?

Comment: Why are you opening the connection. The DataAdapter will open and close the connection if it is closed but if it is open, it leaves it open.

Comment: What is CurrentUserRecordSet? Do Not concatenate strings to build sql statements. Always use parameters.

Comment: Why even use DataAdapters and DatasSets? They fall out of scope before they can be useful.

Comment: God forbid someone be a beginner on stack exchange and ask a question.  Didn't realize it was a cardinal sin to ask a question without first knowing everything about a language (ultimately preventing the need to ask a question in the first place).  Talk about discouraging...  I have to wonder how many beginner programmers @jmcilhinney has completely discouraged from continuing to learn, as this is not the first time I have been "attacked".  Mary, thank you for your assistance.  And, the "CurrentUserRecordSet" is a global variable that stores the current user's authorized recordset (filtering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future visitors, this documentation may help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=net-5.0

Be sure to change the language (upper right corner).

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this would be to wire up an Event Handler for a `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Something like:

```
Protected Sub comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlClient.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim idx As Integer = CInt(ComboBox.SelectedValue)

    'Use idx as a Parameter value for a query for the other information you need from the database.
End Sub
```

Be sure to edit this to suit your needs.

Comment: That should be `CInt(ComboBox.SelectedValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrated how to use `Using...End Using` blocks to ensure that your database objects are disposed. I also demonstrated how to use parameters. I had to guess at the datatype so check you database for the correct value.

After what you called `CurrentUserRecordSet` is set to a location value. The button can be clicked to fill a DataTable and the ComboBox.

When the selection in the combo changes you can retrieve the appropriate row from the `DataTable` with the `Select` method.

```
Private Sub GetData(Location As String)
    Using dbConn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.mydbConnStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * From tblData Where fldLoaction = @Location", dbConn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Location
        dbConn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

'This is a very odd name for a location
'This should be clicked after a value for CurrentUserRecordSet is set from somewhere.
Private CurrentUserRecordSet As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GetData(CurrentUserRecordSet)
    With tsbCboSelect.ComboBox
        .DisplayMember = "fldLastName"
        .ValueMember = "fldID"
        .DataSource = dt
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ID = CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
    Dim row = dt.Select("fldID = ID")(0)
End Sub
```